# Python generators in various languages

Tags: c++, python, programming-languages, lisp

How do you emulate Python style generators in your favorite language? I found [this](http://blog.plt-scheme.org/2007/08/control-and-macros.html) one in Scheme. It must be interesting to see other implementations, especially in those languages that don't have first-class continuations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example in C++ that simulates generators using fibers:

[Yield Return Iterator for Native C++ Using Fibers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/fiber-based_iterator.aspx)

> The "yield return" iterator is a
>   language feature that was created for
>   one reason: simplicity. It is
>   generally much easier to iterate
>   across whole collectionl, storing all
>   context needed in local variables,
>   rather than crafting a complicated,
>   custom iterator object that stores its
>   state across subsequent retrieval
>   operations.

There are also the *primitive* C routines [setjmp, longjmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp/longjmp) to achieve similar results.
(Lua [coroutines](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.11) are implemented with the above method)

Comment: Isn't it Windows-only solution?

Comment: @Paweł: using Fibers is a Windows-only solution, yes.

Comment: Here is implementation of Generators in C++ that does not require platform specific code and yet it extremely short:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29524/Generators-in-C

Comment: nice job @c-smile. You should post an answer.

Answer (score 11):

**I wouldn't use yield at all in Lisp/Scheme.**

'yield' requires some kind of co-routine or continuation facility in the language. Many uses of yield can be implemented in a simpler functional way.

YIELD is basically related to the famous COME-FROM operator. ;-) Here, a call in some place can lead to different places in some other routine, depending on its execution context. So a routine suddenly has multiple entry points whose order is determined at runtime. For simple uses this may be fine, but I would argue that for more complex code reasoning about the code would get harder.

Take the Scheme example linked in the question:

```
(define/y (step) 
  (yield 1)
  (yield 2)
  (yield 3)
  'finished)

(list (step) (step) (step))
```

Calling (step) multiple times returns different values then.

I would just create a closure:

```
(define step
  (let ((state '(1 2 3 finished)))
    (lambda ()
      (pop state))))
```

This breaks above function with a yield into two different things: a variable that carries the state and a simple function that changes the state. The state is no longer implicitly coded into the execution sequence.

```
 (list (step) (step) (step))))
```

One can imagine similar solutions for other uses of yield.

Compare that with the [generators from the Common Lisp SERIES library](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node364.html#SECTION003520000000000000000):

```
(let ((x (generator (scan '(1 2 3 finished)))))
  (list (next-in x)
        (next-in x)
        (next-in x)))
```

If we look at this Python example from another answer

```
def simpleRange(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        yield i

for n in simpleRange(5):
     print(n)
```

we can see that it duplicates the control structure. Both the calling place and the generator use a FOR iteration control structure. Using closures, we can get rid of the use of control structures inside the generator, by only providing the state transition code.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript 1.7+ I usually only have to add a few parentheses and brackets. Everything else is about the same. JavaScript 1.7 introduced pythonic generators and iterators among other things.

### Generator expressions:

```
# Python
(x + 1 for x in y if x > 100)

// JavaScript 1.8+
(x + 1 for (x in y) if (x > 100))
```

### Generators

```
# Python
def simpleRange(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        yield i

for n in simpleRange(5):
     print(n)


// JavaScript 1.7+
function simpleRange(n) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++)
        yield i;
}

for (n in simpleRange(5))
    print(n);
```

### List/Array comprehensions

```
# Python
[x + 1 for x in y if x > 100]

// JavaScript 1.7+
[x + 1 for (x in y) if (x > 100)]
```

Comment: (x + 1 for x in y if x > 100)  isn't a Generator... it is a List Comprehension expression.

Comment: Jean-Lou: Type it into a Python shell after defining an iterable `y` object. The representation is `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fa5b310ec30>`. Tell me that isn't a generator expression.

Answer (score 3):

C++, using [Generators](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29524/Generators-in-C)

Declaration of simple range generator:

```
$generator(range)
{
   int i;
   int _max;
   int _min;

   range(int minv, int maxv):_max(maxv),_min(minv) {}

   $emit(int) // will emit int values. Start of body of the generator.
      for (i = _min; i <= _max; ++i)
         $yield(i); 
   $stop;
};
```

Its usage:

```
range r10(1,10);
for(int n; r10(n);) 
   printf("%d\n",n);
```

Will output

```
1
2 
...
10
```

Answer (score 3):

To @dmitry_vk answer about Common Lisp I would add that in Lisp, actually, generators are not really needed. Their use cases are fully covered by different applications of closures, special variables and macros - without the additional conceptual overhead of learning a new construct.

Sometimes even the built-in constructs will work. Let's look at the example from the Python wiki:

```
# add squares less than 100
from itertools import count, takewhile

sum = 0
square = (i*i for i in count())
bounded_squares = takewhile(lambda x: x < 100, square)
for i in bounded_squares:
   sum += i
```

Using `loop` it can be implemented in a much more straightforward manner:

```
CL-USER> (loop :for i :from 0 :while (< i 100) :sum (expt i 2))
328350
```

As `loop` is much more versatile, than Python's `for` there's no need to introduce special syntax here.

Let's consider another use case - iteration over some custom tree. Suppose the tree is represented by `node`s pointing to their `children`.

```
(defstruct node
  data
  children)
```

We can walk over any tree/subtree with a rather small and simple macro.

```
(defmacro dotree ((var root &optional result-form) &body body)
  `(block nil
     (labels ((traverse (node)
                (let ((,var node))
                  ,@body
                  (dolist (child (children node))
                    (traverse child))
                  ,result-form)))
       (when-it ,root
         (traverse it)))))
```

(Warning: for the sake of more clarity I didn't use `gensym` in it, but you should).

Here's the example of its usage - getting a list of all the leaf nodes:

```
(let (rez)
  (dotree (node tree (reverse rez))
    (when (leafp node)
      (push node rez))))
```

This looks and works just like the standard `dolist` macro. And, as with `dolist` you can stop the iteration at any time, by calling `return`.

Overall, I'm yet to see a **practical** example of generator usage that can't be implemented in Lisp in some less complex way.

P.S. You can also take a look at the [SERIES](http://series.sourceforge.net/) Lisp library, that implemented a similar concept to generators in the 90's. Or [CLAZY](http://common-lisp.net/project/clazy/) - from the late 2000's.

Answer (score 1):

[Monads](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads) can be used to represent generators (even if the semantics are little different).

So any language allowing us to define monadic operations within a special syntax can be used here.

- VB.NET/C# (Linq - but C# already got `yield return`)
- Scala (For-comprehensions)
- Haskell (do-notation)
- F#/OCaml (Computation expressions/Perform)

Ruby can emulate generators through its builtin continuation capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Common Lisp, although does not have native continuations, allows to create delimited continuations using CPS transformers like [cl-cont](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-cont/). So generators in Common Lisp can be written in pretty much the same way as Scheme generators.

By the way, continuation-based generators have one trait that Python and C# generators lack: the `yield` may be called in the dynamic extent of the generator function call. Python and C# generators allow `yield` to be placed only inside the body of a generator.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby:

Generator function:

```
def simple_range(n)
    Enumerator.new do |y|    
        (0..n).each { |v| y.yield(v) }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In general `yield` is redundant in languages that have first class functions. 
For example in [TIScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33662/TIScript-language-a-gentle-extension-of-JavaScript) you can do generators this way:

Generator. Note, it returns inner function.

```
function range( from, to )
{
  var idx = from - 1;
  return function() { if( ++idx <= to ) return idx; } // yields value on call
}
```

And its usage:

```
for( var item in range(12,24) )
  stdout << item << " ";
```

`for(elem in source)` in TIScript is slightly different from JS. If source is a function it gets called and its return value is assigned to the `elem` until the function will not return void (default return value of empty function).